# Back-transformation anid prediction of $\log(X+1)$ estimates in Cox regression

Tags: data-transformation

I have fitted a Cox regression with two predictors $x_1$ and $x_2$ using $\log(1+x_1)$ and $\log(1+x_2)$. I would like to predict $xb$, where $x$ is a matrix of $x_1$ and $x_2$ data and $b$ is the estimated log hazard ratio.

Answer (score 1):

The trick here for your predictions is to recognize that the Cox regression was done in terms of variables having the form $log(1+x)$. So transform your matrix of $x_1,x_2$ data into that form by adding 1 to each element and then taking the log of each element. The $\beta$ coefficients from your Cox model developed in the $log(1+x)$ scales then are applied to the transformed data matrix.

If you instead want log hazard ratios in the original $x_1,x_2$ scales (one possible interpretation of your question) I don't think that there is a simple closed form equation to transform the hazard ratios into those scales. Also, all the confidence interval and similar calculations were performed in the $log(1+x)$ scales. For display in that scale, you could use the procedure in the first paragraph to calculate some examples with $x_1,x_2$ values typical of your data.

Comment: If I would use $log(x)$ instead of $log(1+x)$ the the linear predictor of $fit <- coxph(Surv(time,event)~log(x1)+log(x2),x=T,y=T)$ would be $lp <- exp(x)%*%(coef/100)$? Is this correct? Is it possible to do the same transformation for $log(1+x)$? Many thanks!

Comment: Sorry! I meant fit<−coxph(Surv(time,event)~log(x1)+log(x2),x=T,y=T) would be lp<−exp(x)%*%coef/100?

Comment: Could you say how you got the relation for the linear predictor that you present in your comment? Even if it's correct, my sense is that you will best avoid errors if you use the transformation of $x$ variables I recommend in the first paragraph.